# como establezco datos dentro de la propiedad context en react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-redux

estoy migrando a la nueva version de react-router y me di cuenta que hay una nueva funcion llamada createBrowserRouter

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
 {
   path: "/",
   element: <div>index</div>,
   loader: async (param) => {
     console.log(param)
     const { auth } = store.getState()
     if(auth.isAuth)
      throw redirect("/login");
    return null
   }
 },
 {
   path: "/login",
   element: <div />
 },
]);
```

el parametro param es un objeto que contiene un context, un params y un request, mi idea es obtener los datos de sesion dentro del context, como establezco esos datos dentro del mismo ?